# YouTube API - Querying by publish date

Tags: api, youtube, gdata-api, gdata

I'm writing a webapp that uses the YouTube Code API to do specific types of searches.  In this case, I'm trying to search for all videos that match a query, and which were uploaded between two dates. [This document](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Displaying_a_list_of_videos) says I can use published-min and published-max parameters, while [this one](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html) says I can use updated-min and updated-max.

Both of these parameter sets cause YouTube to return an error:

- [published-min](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos?q=test&published-min=2011-04-05T00:00:00-06:00&published-max=2011-04-14T00:00:00-06:00&max-results=50) returns "This service does not support the 'published-min parameter"
- [updated-min](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos?q=test&updated-min=2011-04-05T00:00:00-06:00&updated-max=2011-04-14T00:00:00-06:00&max-results=50) returns "This service does not support the 'updated-max' parameter"
- [With neither](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos?q=test&max-results=50) returns a correct result set.

How can I limit my result set to hits within a specified date range?

Comment: FWIW, the API does seem to recognize the special filter values used in the regular YouTube search: `?q=Test%2C+today`, `?q=Test%2C+this+week`, `?q=Test%2C+this+month`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Reference Guide for YouTube's Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html) doesn't list anything that would suggest the possibility to filter on time interval in general.

The `published-min` argument is only advertised in the ["User activity feeds" section](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#User_activity_feeds) which is something different and probably not the thing you wanted. Or is it?

The `updated-min` argument in your link is referenced in a generic gdata context. It looks like they intended to describe all the things common to all the specialized APIs, but somehow `updated-min` isn't available everywhere.

When it comes to your very problem. I would suggest sorting on time (`orderby=published`) and do the filtering on the client side. I know this is not the optimal way, but the only one I can see with what Google gives us.

Comment: As depressing as it is, that "solution" works. I hereby reprimand and scald YouTube for such a horrid implementation. In what universe can a database or API not be queried by entry date? :(

Comment: YouTube API fails to execute with a start-index of 1000 or more. My sample data I'm using to target my search has a result set of 3300+ by one user. Any idea how to get around that little problem?

Comment: I know it's even more stupid, but maybe there's some field which a closed set of values like `category` in which you could do the filtering separately and merge the results yourself?

Comment: Anyway, I suggest filing some request/complaint to them. Maybe someday someone will do something about it. I believe http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/ is the right place to do it.

Answer (score 7):

youtube api v3 supports `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` parameters with search results. For example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={{YOUKEY}}&channelId={{CHANNELID}}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50&publishedAfter=2014-09-21T00:00:00Z&publishedBefore=2014-09-22T02:00:00Z
```

Comment: you should mind that whoever comes here, it is not real publish date. It is the content creation date which is really bothersome for some videos.