# search for youtube videos within specified date range using youtube api or gdata in C#

Tags: c#, youtube-api, date-range

I have read google developer resources and didn't get an answer to what i am seeking.
I am trying to write a query to get a a list videos from a channel with in the specified date range. Can this be done.

Any example or recommendation you might have particularly for .Net would be great.

Well i have schedule that runs every night and then grabs  threads from facebook, twitter and linked in . I am able to do that using oauth and writing subjective queries to return resultsets from each social API for a given date range for e.g from yesterday till today.

Just can;t seem to find anything for youtube api.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure why you posted the link. yes I tried.

Comment: There are no date ranges,Jonathan 'a one liner comment definitely doesn't, help. I think you can keep the comment to yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [YouTube API - Querying by publish date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768711/youtube-api-querying-by-publish-date)

Comment: Thanks for showing the link, but unfortunately that's wrong. See this link from Google although its experimental but it tells that you could use query attributes in version 2.0,2.1. https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial  this also shows extensive research....